# Passing arguments to shell command

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a shell script that I am executing inside a python script and i want to pass two variables to the script as arguments.I used $ sign but it's not working.
this is the shell script:

```
path='/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/media/Page_00287_jpg.rf.6a823c5ce3894f223a0e8f4ec20b11b2/article1'
save='/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/media/Page_00287_jpg.rf.6a823c5ce3894f223a0e8f4ec20b11b2/article1/annotations.json'
call('python "/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/mmdetection/tools/test.py" \
"/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/models/second_model_conf.py" \
"/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/models/second_model_checkpoint.pth" \
--cfg-options data.test.ann_file=$save \
data.test.img_prefix=$path \
--format-only \
--options "jsonfile_prefix=path"', shell=True)
```

Comment: I don't see that your script would reference any parameter passed to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess string interpolation can be used to pass your Python variables to the `args` of the `call` command. For example, if you use [`fstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), the code will look like this:

```py
path='/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/media/Page_00287_jpg.rf.6a823c5ce3894f223a0e8f4ec20b11b2/article1'
save='/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/media/Page_00287_jpg.rf.6a823c5ce3894f223a0e8f4ec20b11b2/article1/annotations.json'
call(f'python "/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/mmdetection/tools/test.py" \
"/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/models/second_model_conf.py" \
"/home/ranim/Documents/mmdet/models/second_model_checkpoint.pth" \
--cfg-options data.test.ann_file={save} \
data.test.img_prefix={path} \
--format-only \
--options "jsonfile_prefix=path"', shell=True)
```

Comment: Please [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) then :)

Comment: Ah sorry it's my first time posting and getting an answer on stackoverflow xD